# Changing a QlikView document's zoom level programmatically

Tags: activex, zooming, ocx, qlikview

I know the following QlikView API methods:

```
ActiveDocument.ActiveSheet.FitZoomToWindow

ActiveDocument.ActiveSheet.ApplyZoomToAllSheets
```

However, I want a method to change the zoom level to a chosen level, for example "Zoom to 75%".

Is there any way to do this with the QlikView OCX control (via C#), or via QlikView's API in macros?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (taken from the official API Guide):

```
set mysheet=ActiveDocument.ActiveSheet
set sp=mysheet.GetProperties
sp.ZoomFactor = 0.9
mysheet.SetProperties sp
```

Regards
Stefan